# How would I write up an integral symbol, along with the two numbers to the right of it, in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

Title says it all (I think). I just want to replicate math which would normally be done in Year 11/12, and got sorta stuck here.

Any help?

Comment: @cmhughes Hey, that works. Post that as an answer, and the award's yours.

Comment: You might find [this](http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/equation.html?locale=default) useful: write what you want and it converts to LaTeX. Then copy/paste in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use one of a few options- the examples below are in in-line mathmode- if you're in display-math mode, then there's no need for `\displaystyle`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item $\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$
  \item $\int\limits_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$
  \item $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

For future reference, have a look at [`The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/lshort) which covers this, and a lot more.

Comment: Here you go, as promised.

Comment: Note that the convention in most parts of the US is to have the "d" in italics, but preceded by a thin space: `\int_a^b f(x) \, dx`